# how to solve this error in react js

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am learning react.js. I have run all commands which needed for setup react js
but when I run `npm start` this command give me the error. I have not understood the problem.
When I run `npm start` the error is

> Error: `output.path` needs to be an absolute path or `/`.
>       at Object.setFs (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\reactApp\node_modules\webpac
>   k-dev-middleware\lib\Shared.js:88:11)
>       at Shared (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\reactApp\node_modules\webpack-dev-
>   middleware\lib\Shared.js:214:8)
>       at module.exports (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\reactApp\node_modules\webp
>   ack-dev-middleware\middleware.js:22:15)
>       at new Server (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\reactApp\node_modules\webpack-
>   dev-server\lib\Server.js:56:20)
>       at startDevServer (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\reactApp\node_modules\webp
>   ack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:379:12)
>       at processOptions (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\reactApp\node_modules\webp
>   ack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:317:3)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\reactApp\node_modules\
>   webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:441:1)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
>
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601 npm ERR! argv "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\
>   node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "start" npm ERR! node v7.3.0 npm
>   ERR! npm  v3.10.10 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR!
>   package.json@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server` npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the package.json@1.0.0 start script
>   'webpack-dev-server'. npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version
>   of node.js and npm installed. npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely
>   a problem with the package.json package,
>
> npm ERR! not with npm itself. npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails
>   on your system: npm ERR!     webpack-dev-server npm ERR! You can get
>   information on how to open an issue for this project with: npm ERR!
>   npm bugs package.json npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get
>   their info via: npm ERR!     npm owner ls package.json npm ERR! There
>   is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\reactApp\npm-debug.log

Comment: As the error says, your Webpack config is wrong. `output.path` needs to be an absolute path or `/`. Read the docs for an example of how to solve this: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/

Answer (score 1):

I meet this problem yesterday,and I finally solved it today,and I wish it can help you.
in your webpack.config.js, you should make the path an absolute path,do it as the following:

```
  output:{
    path:__dirname + '/dist',
    filename:"build.js"
  },
```

__dirname is the path of your project,dist is the path you want to save your build.js,
and in your index.html

```
 <script src="/build.js">

    </script>
```

the reason is that the webpack has updated to webpack2

Comment: replacing './any-dir' with __dirname + '/any-dir' in webpack.config.js worked for me .